# How To Combine Different Flag Columns Into a Single Row

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and I have the following table:

```
ID1  Team  HasGender  HasAge  HasHeight

 1    Blue   1         (NULL)    1
 2    Blue   1            1    (NULL)
```

...and I want to create a single row from that showing:

```
 ID1  Team  HasGender  HasAge  HasHeight
  1   Blue    1          1        1
```

I don't so much care which row to bring, I just need all the flags put into the one row.

I tried IsNULL, using Group by with Max (didn't work as the flag fields are Bit types), and then I tried the following using COALESCE and a self join but still it didn't work; it brought back multiples of the rows, and the flags still didn't fill out as I wanted them to:

```
  SELECT t1.ID, t1.Team,
          Gender=COALESCE(t1.HasGender, t2.HasGender),
          Age=COALESCE(t1.HasAge, t2.HasAge),
          Height=COALESCE(t1.HasHeight, t2.HasHeight)
  FROM Table t1 INNER JOIN Table t2
  ON t1.Team = t2.Team
```

I should note the table has 3 or 4 rows of such flags, so when I do join I seem to get multiples back.

Thanks in advance,

Veronica

Comment: Just to make sure, your flags are Nullable Bits, meaning that you can have 0, 1 and *NULL* for value? If so, what happens when there are 3 rows with the values '1', '0' and 'null'?

Comment: They are indeed Nullable Bits, but all 1's or NULLs, no 0's in the table (it's not a big one thankfully, just a few hundred rows).

Comment: DIdi you find any valid solution?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for you, there is no way to do MAX(bit). This means that you can either convert it to another data type (smallint being favored because it's small), or you can use a count :

```
SELECT
    Team, 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(HasGender)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasGender
    CASE WHEN COUNT(HasAge)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasAge
    CASE WHEN COUNT(HasHeight)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasHeight
FROM Table
GROUP BY Team
```

This only works if you have no 0s though. If you do have 0s you will have to make a conditional count (but at that point I'd go with the casting option).

To account for 0s, each row would need to look like

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE HasGender WHEN 1 THEN 1)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasGender
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(ID1), Team, MAX(CONVERT(tinyint, HasGender)), MAX(CONVERT(tinyint, HasAge)), MAX(CONVERT(tinyint, HasHeight))
FROM Table
GROUP BY Team
```

EDIT:
Converting data to tinyint type

Comment: Unfortunately I get the following message: Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator.   Because the flag fields are Nullable bits

Comment: I'm glad of having been of some help, please mark it as valid answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your bit columns as an tinyint so you can use them in an aggregate. Something like this.

```
SELECT t1.ID
    , t1.Team
    , Gender = MAX(CAST(COALESCE(t1.HasGender, t2.HasGender) as tinyint))
    , Age = MAX(CAST(COALESCE(t1.HasAge, t2.HasAge) as tinyint))
    , Height = MAX(CAST(COALESCE(t1.HasHeight, t2.HasHeight) as tinyint))
  FROM Table t1 INNER JOIN Table t2
  ON t1.Team = t2.Team
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select min(ID1) as ID1 , Team ,iif(sum(CAST(HasGender   AS INT))>0,1,0) as HasGender  , iif(sum(CAST(HasAge AS INT))>0,1,0) as HasAge ,iif(sum(CAST(HasHeight AS INT))>0,1,0) as HasHeight
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.